# How to show previous list view using back button

Tags: android, listview

Suppose I have displayed a list view(say lv1) of 3 items. when clicked on any of them I get new list view(say lv2). when again I click one of them I get another view. Now when I click back button i want to go back to previous list view i.e. lv2 and again when back button is pressed I want to show list view lv1. can anybody tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to shown different listviews in different activities. Follow Shailendra Rajawat's guide. Every time you click on an item, start a new Activity. So by default, when you press back button, the previous activity will be shown.
2. If you want to achieve this function within one activity. Use a variable to indicate which listview should be currently shown. Something like:

   `private int listIndex=0;` every time you click on an item:`listIndex++;` and call `setContentView(lvX);` to show new listView.

   Override the `onBackPress()` method:

   ```
   if(listIndex>0) *so at the first listView backbutton will be ignored */
   listIndex--;
     switch(listIndex) {

      case 0: 

      setContentView(lv0); break;

   /* some other cases*/

   ........}
   ```

Something like this.

EDIT: I tested my method. Actually, there are three ways to refresh the listView.

```
package viewTest.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ViewTestActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter0;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    private String[] array0;
    private String[] array1;
    private ListView lv0;
    private ListView lv1;
    private RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    array0 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LV0);
    array1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LV1);

    adapter0 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, array0);
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, array1);

    lv0 = new ListView(this);
    lv1 = new ListView(this);
    layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

    lv0.setAdapter(adapter0);
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    lv0.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
//Method1: change the adapter to refresh the listview
//              lv0.setAdapter(adapter1);

//Method2: use the layout to remove and add views
//              layout.removeAllViews();
//              layout.addView(lv1);

//Method3: setContentView() directly;
            setContentView(lv1);

        }
    });
//      layout.addView(lv0);
        setContentView(lv0);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to destroy current view when moving to next view?

Comment: You don't need to destroy something. Just prepare the several listview and call 'setContentView(listview_object)' and the screen will show the one you want.

Comment: I am getting only black screen when i call setContentView(ListObj).

Comment: Hmm, I have implemented similar functions on my project. OK, I will check it tonight after I get back home.

Comment: Hey, I just tested this method on my laptop and I found it worked. Have you set the adapter to lv1? If not, the listview shows nothing. I edited my answer and pasted my code for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

what you have described here it is obvious in Android Activity life cycle because when you hit back button it finish the current Activity and show the top most Activity on Stack . So please explain what problem you are getting here .

Answer (score 0):

You can put some boolean to true if the second list view is showing. When back button is pressed, look at the boolean and change the listView to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

as a neat and clean approach every screen you want to show on back press , should be on activity stack , so for every such views start a new activity even if they have same UI components . 
if this approach is not suitable save data of every visible entity on navigations they reset views as per need by overRiding onBackPress().